# How to show a set is closed.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Show $A = \{f \in C([0,1], R) \ | \max f(x) \le 1 \}$ is closed.

I tried to show $A$ is compact, which is not compact; and I tried to show by definition of closed set but failed.

I am thinking of showing the limit is exist in the set but I am not sure how to show the limit exist first and then show it is in the set.

Comment: uniform metric is implied?

Comment: What do you mean with $f(x)\le 1$? Is $x$ a given point? Or you mean $f(x)\le 1$ for every $x\in[0,1]$?

Comment: @ajotatxe You're right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $f$ be a limit point of $A$. There exists a sequence $f_n$ in $A$ such that $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$. Since $\max f_n(x) \le 1$, $f_n(x) \le 1$ for all $x$ and $n$; taking the limit yields $f(x) \le 1$ for all $x$. Hence $\max f(x) \le 1$. Furthermore, since $f$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions, $f$ is continuous. Therefore $f\in A$. This shows that $A$ is closed.

Comment: By Weirstrass theorem, it is true that if certain conditions are met, there is a limit $f$. I am wondering if the inverse statement is true?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I do not get the reason for the following statement:There exists a sequence fn in A such that fn→f uniformly on C([0,1],ℝ)"

Comment: Sorry, I meant $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 5):

Let $f \in \bar A$. Then, there's a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n\ge0} \subset A$ such that: $f_n \rightarrow f$.

As $\{f_n\}_{n\ge0} \subset A$: $f_n(x) \le 1$, $\forall$ $n \ge 0$ and $x \in [0,1]$.

This gives: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) \le 1, \ \forall \ x \in [0,1]$$

That's: $$f(x) \le 1, \ \forall \ x \in [0,1]$$

Therefore $f \in A$. This shows $\bar A \subset A$.

Comment: After the question has been edited: the new argument is similar to the one in this answer. Just alter some details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

- Let $\phi(f) = \max \{ f(x) : x \in [0,1] \}$.
- Prove that $\phi$ is a continuous functional $C([0,1], \mathbb R) \to \mathbb R$.
- Note that $A=\phi^{-1}(-\infty,1]$ and conclude that $A$ is closed.